# R - How to change the transition frames that show up in an animated plot to be only the ones that are present with values

Tags: r, plot, animated-gif, gganimate

I have made an animated plot using ggplot and gganimate. When setting the transition to Year the frames increment by a fraction (think like 2 months) of each year until they get to the next Year with values.

As the years with values are not a linear constant increase (ie 2000, 2001, 2002) and instead (2000, 2005, 2010 etc) there is part of the animation that just has an empty plot.

How would I set the transition or some other parameter so the only frames that show up are ones with values?

Plot code is this, from what I have read the {frame_time} part maybe is the issue? or else I believe I am missing a parameter.

```
homicide_gdp_df %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = `Intentional_homicide_rates_per_100,000`, y = GDP_per_capita_USD, color = Country)) +
  geom_point() +
  labs(
    title = "GDP vs Homicide Rate",
    subtitle = "Year: {frame_time}",
    x = "Homicide rates per log(100,000)",
    y = "GDP per Capita (USD)"
  ) +
  scale_x_log10() +
  transition_time(Year)
```

Thank you.

Comment: I wonder if `transition_states` might be more appropriate?